# What is causing Undefined offset: 0 php

Tags: php

I am trying get coordinate from addresses, but having an error which is called undefined offset. Actually array is not null and when I try to get coordinate one by one, I can get grab it without a problem. But when I try get all at once error pops up.

```
    $addr = [];
    foreach($newHtml as $link){

        $htm = pageContent($link);
        $paths = new \DOMXPath($htm);
        $routes = $paths->query("//body/div[@class='p-main']//table/tr[4]/td");
        foreach ($routes as $route) {
            $addr = trim($route->nodeValue);
        }

        $address = urlencode($addr);
        $response = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$address}&key=MY_API_KEY");
        $result = json_decode($response);

        $lat[] = trim($result->results[0]->geometry->location->lat);
        $lng[] = trim($result->results[0]->geometry->location->lng);
    }

    var_dump($lat, $lng);
```

Response gives this;

> ["results"]=>   array(1) {
>       [0]=>
>       object(stdClass)#696 (6) {
>         ["address_components"]=>
>         array(8) {
>           [0]=>
>           object(stdClass)#684 (3) {
>             ["long_name"]=>
>             string(9) "Ｄ２１"
>             ["short_name"]=>
>             string(9) "Ｄ２１"
>             ["types"]=>
>             array(1) {
>               [0]=>
>               string(7) "premise"
>             }
>           }
>           [1]=>
>           object(stdClass)#709 (3) {
>             ["long_name"]=>
>             string(1) "1"
>             ["short_name"]=>
>             string(1) "1"
>             ["types"]=>
>             array(3) {
>               [0]=>
>               string(9) "political"
>               [1]=>
>               string(11) "sublocality"
>               [2]=>
>               string(19) "sublocality_level_4"
>             }
>           }
>           [2]=>
>           object(stdClass)#714 (3) {
>             ["long_name"]=>
>             string(7) "5 Chome"
>             ["short_name"]=>
>             string(7) "5 Chome"
>             ["types"]=>
>             array(3) {
>               [0]=>
>               string(9) "political"
>               [1]=>
>               string(11) "sublocality"
>               [2]=>
>               string(19) "sublocality_level_3"
>             }
>           }
>           [3]=>
>           object(stdClass)#698 (3) {
>             ["long_name"]=>
>             string(8) "Furuedai"
>             ["short_name"]=>
>             string(8) "Furuedai"
>             ["types"]=>
>             array(3) {
>               [0]=>
>               string(9) "political"
>               [1]=>
>               string(11) "sublocality"
>               [2]=>
>               string(19) "sublocality_level_2"
>             }
>           }
>           [4]=>
>           object(stdClass)#680 (3) {
>             ["long_name"]=>
>             string(5) "Suita"
>             ["short_name"]=>
>             string(5) "Suita"
>             ["types"]=>
>             array(2) {
>               [0]=>
>               string(8) "locality"
>               [1]=>
>               string(9) "political"
>             }
>           }
>           [5]=>
>           object(stdClass)#701 (3) {
>             ["long_name"]=>
>             string(16) "Osaka Prefecture"
>             ["short_name"]=>
>             string(16) "Osaka Prefecture"
>             ["types"]=>
>             array(2) {
>               [0]=>
>               string(27) "administrative_area_level_1"
>               [1]=>
>               string(9) "political"
>             }
>           }
>           [6]=>
>           object(stdClass)#695 (3) {
>             ["long_name"]=>
>             string(5) "Japan"
>             ["short_name"]=>
>             string(2) "JP"
>             ["types"]=>
>             array(2) {
>               [0]=>
>               string(7) "country"
>               [1]=>
>               string(9) "political"
>             }
>           }
>           [7]=>
>           object(stdClass)#699 (3) {
>             ["long_name"]=>
>             string(8) "565-0874"
>             ["short_name"]=>
>             string(8) "565-0874"
>             ["types"]=>
>             array(1) {
>               [0]=>
>               string(11) "postal_code"
>             }
>           }
>         }
>         ["formatted_address"]=>
>         string(69) "5 Chome-1-Ｄ２１ Furuedai, Suita, Osaka Prefecture 565-0874, Japan"
>         ["geometry"]=>
>         object(stdClass)#690 (3) {
>           ["location"]=>
>           object(stdClass)#694 (2) {
>             ["lat"]=>
>             float(34.8097093)
>             ["lng"]=>
>             float(135.5119112)
>           }
>           ["location_type"]=>
>           string(7) "ROOFTOP"
>           ["viewport"]=>
>           object(stdClass)#689 (2) {
>             ["northeast"]=>
>             object(stdClass)#688 (2) {
>               ["lat"]=>
>               float(34.811058280291)
>               ["lng"]=>
>               float(135.51326018029)
>             }
>             ["southwest"]=>
>             object(stdClass)#692 (2) {
>               ["lat"]=>
>               float(34.808360319709)
>               ["lng"]=>
>               float(135.51056221971)
>             }
>           }
>         }
>         ["place_id"]=>
>         string(27) "ChIJUY4O7kP7AGARu_UB4lJPFWU"
>         ["plus_code"]=>
>         object(stdClass)#687 (2) {
>           ["compound_code"]=>
>           string(30) "RG56+VQ Suita, 大阪府 Japan"
>           ["global_code"]=>
>           string(11) "8Q6QRG56+VQ"
>         }
>         ["types"]=>
>         array(2) {
>           [0]=>
>           string(13) "establishment"
>           [1]=>
>           string(17) "point_of_interest"
>         }
>       }   }   ["status"]=>   string(2) "OK"

Comment: Use print_r($newHtml); to inspect the array $newHtml, you will see that key 0 does not exist there. It will return NULL and throw that error.

Comment: You should check that `$response` and `$result` are `false` which would indicate that either of those operations have failed. If they are OK - can you add what `$response` gives in the question.

Comment: I added what response gives in the question @NigelRen

Comment: As your doing this in a loop - is it only running once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line causes an error:

```
$result->results[0]
```

You need to check if `$result->results` has 0 key.

**UPDATE:**

To troubleshoot your problem you need to catch response that you do not expect:

```
$response = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$address}&key=MY_API_KEY");
$result = json_decode($response);

try {
    $lat[] = trim($result->results[0]->geometry->location->lat);
    $lng[] = trim($result->results[0]->geometry->location->lng);
} catch (\Exeption $e) {
    var_dump($result);
}
```

When an exception occurs, you will see the response that causes your problem, and then you need to add a response format check based on what you received.

For example if you receive something like this:

```
{"results":[], "status": "ZERO_RESULTS"}
```

Your code should looks like this:

```
$response = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$address}&key=MY_API_KEY");

$result = json_decode($response);

if(!empty($result->results)){
    $lat[] = trim($result->results[0]->geometry->location->lat);
    $lng[] = trim($result->results[0]->geometry->location->lng);
}
```

See also https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e4b1465c427e42ca379f3a16a75f7d8a3250031d  - try this example with your response (json)

Comment: Can you provide your response in json format?

Comment: @Barbie try to check your variables with `var_dump` on each step

Comment: I think I find the problem. I guess one of the address is doesn't have coordinate. And it returns zero results. it can be effects that address

Comment: @Barbie try to add response checking before getting lon, lat data from it.

Comment: Mmm, how can I do it? could you give an example?

Comment: @Barbie add example to my answer

Comment: Thank you so much, really. I'll check this as answer.

Comment: @Barbie You are welcome! I'm glad I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
    $locations = json_decode($response, true);

    if(is_array($locations)) {
   $lat =   $locations['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
   $lng =   $locations['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];

  }
```

json_decode -->will return object array

json_decode with second parameter as true return as array

Comment: I added fetched data in question.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/497fc7059b327da98fcc9c712fb8f1ec3a1ea694

Check  link for reference